# Performance of system() on Windows.(C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

```
int result = 0;
CString pCommand;
CString pIP;
pIP.Format("1.1.1.1");
pCommand.Format("netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=\"TestRule : %s\"",pIP.GetString());

result = system(pCommand.GetString());

if ( Result == 1 )
{
    printf("Firewall Rule Not Found.\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Firewall Rule Found.\n");
}
```

The code is run every time my Application Receive a TCP Handshake Request (WINSOCK.h).

Given the following code above I have the following Questions.

1. Could I Replicate the result of the code above using ShellExecute/ShellExecuteEx?
2. If yes, would it give better performance than the system call,or would it be okay to continue using the code above?
3. Would it be better to Use CreateProcess,Rather than system() or ShellExecute, and get the same results?

Comment: Don't use system, don't use create process, but use the windows API directly from C++. 
[enumerating firewall rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ics/c-enumerating-firewall-rules)

Comment: better performance always requires you to measure, how else would you know what is better. First I'd measure the difference between the call to `system` and executing the command directly

Comment: @Pepijn Kramer, Thank you so much for the Link! That was way better and much faster and Clearer to boot! 

I didn't even know Windows Firewall had an API! Thanks a Lot, I was able whip up a quick code for my use case!

Comment: @AzrielElijay Cool! And nice you could get it working so fast, I've never used this part of the API.  But I know that it usually pays of to browse the API documentation (stuff keeps on getting added) :)  And in general if there is a commandline utility there is also an api that can do it

Comment: @PepjinKramer Since I'm not a programmer by trade and doing this out of my hobby for an Old MMORPG, this was an eye opener for me. I didn't know Windows had APIs like this. It's a good thing I had experience with COM Objects too due to VBA if not I'll be leaking a lot of it. Thank you for such a Concise answer!